# YA Ghost-story - Flowers sent by dead boyfriend

Tags: story-identification, young-adult

This was a young-adult ghost story that I read in the early 1990's

- A teen boy sends red roses to his girlfriend while he is away holidaying with his family.
- The girl tells him the roses kept arrived dead or dying
- He complains to florist and they send again, this time they're white instead of red - signifying death.
- The girl learns that the boy has died on holiday (possibly sailing?)
- Girl realises she can still see or speak to boy in the attic of her home.

Comment: Why would people downvote this? trish adams, is there any more information you can give us? Was it a novel, a short story, a novella? What was on the front cover? Do you remember any characters' names? The more information we have, the more likely it is that someone can work out the answer for you.

Comment: @JamesSheridan - I suspect it got downvoted for being a bit "stream-of-consciousness-y". I've edited it to make the order of events clearer.